# Writing from Excel sheet to a table

Tags: python, jquery, html, excel, html-table

I am looking to write certain columns of data from an excel sheet to a HTML table. Not looking to write specific/fixed cells into the table always, need to do this based on conditions. For example, if I have a table with columns Name/Age/Occupation, I would like to make an HTML table using just columns Name and Occupation. Also, within Name, I would only like to write the names starting with 'N' onto the table and corresponding Occupation. The Excel sheet dynamically changes with new data everytime. Essentially, I would not want to write specific cells or range of cells into the table but only the data based on conditions I set. Any suggestions using python/html/jquery or other methods are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First you should edit the Excel file, export it as a `.csv` file and then work on the file using a program language of your preference. It would be much much more complicated if you try to work on the `.xls` or `.xlsx` files. I recommend using `python` with its library `panda` that works on csv files.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing excel files, I've had good success using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) 
 A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files